# What is the best way to model a ragged hierarchy in SSAS for both ROLAP and MOLAP?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, msas

I'm currently trying to model a ragged hierarchy in SSAS and I'm stuck.

First, I was trying to model it like so:

```
ItemKey,Level0Key,Level1Key,Level2Key
Item1,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-1
Item2,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-1
Item3,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-2
**Item4,Lvl0-1, , **
```

Where the last line in this example had blanks for the "missing" levels.

Here, ROLAP managed to interpret the hierarchy okay, but MOLAP mode wound up mis-classifying members from the fact table, so the aggregations were off.

Next, I changed it to this based on the AdventureWorksDW example SalesTerritory dimension which was a ragged hierarchy:

```
ItemKey,Level0Key,Level1Key,Level2Key
Item1,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-1
Item2,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-1
Item3,Lvl0-1,Lvl1-1,Lvl2-2
**Item4,Lvl0-1,Item4,Item4**
```

I'm taking advantage of the HideIfOnlyChildAndSameNameAsParent to hide the members.

Now MOLAP's numbers line up, but in ROLAP land, I'm having major slowdowns because level 1 of my hierarchy has about 10000 members - SSAS goes out to lunch on an expansion.

So obviously I'm missing something, but I haven't seen many examples on the "right" way to do a ragged hierarchy.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, "ragged hierarchy" is an immediate translation to "parent-child" for me. You'd want it to go like so:

```
ItemID    ItemKey    ParentID
1         Lvl0-1     null
2         Lvl1-1     1
3         Lvl2-1     2
4         Lvl2-2     2
5         Item1      3
6         Item2      3
7         Item3      4
8         Item4      1
```

SSAS will generate this Parent/Child for you once you tell it what the `ParentID` is. Rather automagic. Also, here I used `ItemID` as a surrogate key, and used the `ParentID` which pointed to that. There are a long list of reasons to use integers, but for Parent/Child, what you should do is use the ID as the Key column, and then add `ItemKey` as an attribute/relationship to said key column. You can then order `Item` (missing from this schema) by `Attribute Key` and select `ItemKey`. You can also choose whether or not to show that property to the user.

SSAS, by default, assumes that a `null` or self-referential parent key is a root node. I generally use `null` because they're easier for me to see when I'm scrolling through records. But, this is a preference thing.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid of that - I was trying not to do parent child.

Comment: @Eli: Why? Parent/Child is a fantastic solution to the problem. What were you afriad of?